# Stratified random assignment

Tags: r, random

I need to use stratified random assignment of 8 subjects  to control and treatment groups based on their body condition score (BCS) which can be high or low.

```
1. high
2. high
3. high
4. high
5. low
6. low
7. low
8. low
```

I need to randomly get 2 groups with equal number of high and low BCS in each group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using data.table package you can do the following (assuming your subject ids are in a column names subject)

```
library(data.table)

foo = setDT(your.data.frame) # transform your df into a data.table

dat = foo[, .SD[sample(.N, round(.N * 0.5))], by = BCS] # sample 50% of rows of each BCS

foo[subject %in% dat[, .(subject), status := "treatment"][is.na(status), status:= "control"] # assign a control treatment column
```